# Problems with arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following code where you want to keep all records of my office in an array. The problem is that by giving him a "var_dump" I only print the first record.

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 class conect{
    private $data;

    public function __construct($user, $pass){
           $this -> data = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=indvalid_hya; charset=utf8', $user, $pass);
           }

    public function conexion(){
           return $this -> data;
           }   
 }

 class uuid{
    public $conect;
    public $values = array();

    public function select(){
           $this -> conect = new conect("root", "qppx3cqpp");
           $data = $this -> conect -> conexion();

           $dbquery = $data -> prepare("SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT");
           $dbquery -> execute();

           $data = $dbquery -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           foreach($data as $key => $c):
                   return $values[] = $c['ID'];
           endforeach;


    }
 }


 $c = new uuid();
 $a = $c -> select();
 var_dump($a);
```

?>

Comment: Read up on what `return` does: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: Correct your code by change following line.

From

foreach($data as $key => $c):
                   return $values[] = $c['ID'];
endforeach;

TO

foreach($data as $key => $c):
    $values[] = $c['ID'];
endforeach;
return $values[];

return array after foreach look  return $values[];

thanks
hope it helps

Comment: @codewizz If you want it marked up, post it as an answer rather than a comment :)

Comment: @Juan Morales
Answer posted
please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Solution:

Correct your code by change following line. 
From

```
foreach($data as $key => $c): 
 return $values[] = $c['ID']; 
endforeach;
```

TO

```
foreach($data as $key => $c): 
   $values[] = $c['ID']; 
endforeach; 
return $values; 
// return array after foreach look return $values[];
```

thanks 
hope it helps